# 'Reshape' object is not iterable

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to combine encoder and decoder in keras

Here is minimal code to test

#### Data load

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train[:5,:,:,]
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_train
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
```

#### Creating the model

```
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
encoderOutputFlat = Flatten()(encoded)
encoder = Model(input_img, encoderOutputFlat)

decoder_input = Input(Reshape((7,7,32)))(encoderOutputFlat)
decoder = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_input)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)

auto_input = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
encoded = encoder(auto_input)
decoded = decoder(encoded)
autoencoder = Model(auto_input, decoded)
```

Here I have the error

```
decoder_input = Input(Reshape((7,7,32)))(encoderOutputFlat)
```

How can I make it work? 
I want to train it as one model. Then get values from encoder. Then I want to use decoder on the data separately.

Comment: What is the line that errors supposed to do? That line by itself makes no sense.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I want to use a vector as an input for the decoder

Comment: You don't need to define a new Input instance for that. Just use encoderOutputFlat

Comment: Can you, please show me how to get conv layer having "flat" ? I need two input layers (two models connected into one for training)